# Google_Map _Flutter has some functions undefined

Tags: flutter, google-maps

After Updating my Google_map_flutter to version 2.0.6, The following functions are underlined red and it telling me those functions are undefined.
1.Maptype
2.CameraPosition
3.LatLong

I have restarted the android studio and even changed to use Vs code, but still same issue.

Comment: Do flutter clean and then run pub get. Should work fine

Comment: Does running flutter clean and flutter pub get as suggested by Ganesh solve your issue?